# throw() with clang++ shows possible memory leak

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, clang

I have a piece of code, which when compiled with g++ does not show any memory leaks.
Whereas, the same when compiled with clang++ shows, possible memory leak.

Here's the trace,

```
==7115==
==7115== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7115==     in use at exit: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==7115==   total heap usage: 2,324 allocs, 2,323 frees, 2,166,060 bytes allocated
==7115==
==7115== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==7115==    at 0x4C2BFB9: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:762)
==7115==    by 0x4129830: __cxxabiv1::__calloc_with_fallback(unsigned long, unsigned long) (in /opt/xxx/lib64/libc++abi.so.1)
==7115==    by 0x4128946: __cxa_get_globals (in /opt/xxx/lib64/libc++abi.so.1)
==7115==    by 0x412B287: __cxa_throw (in /opt/xxx/lib64/libc++abi.so.1)
==7115==    by 0x4E712AE: Lib::GenCmd::RaiseException(Status, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) (LibBase.cpp:291)
==7115==
==7115== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7115==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7115==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7115==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7115==    still reachable: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==7115==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7115==
==7115== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
```

Well, its not possible to share the code snippet, but I can tell you RaiseException() is the function where I have a call made to **throw()** (at line 291) an exception. Here's the function snippet:

```
void GenCmd::RaiseException(Status status, std::string AdditionalMsg) throw(Status) {
    s_last_error = GetStatusString(status);

    if (false == AdditionalMsg.empty()) {
        s_last_error = s_last_error + AdditionalMsg;
    }
    throw(status);
}
```

Status is a structure, defined as below (along with default, parameterized & copy constructors)

```
typedef struct _Status {
    const u64_t m_status          : 8;
    const u64_t ReservedByte1     : 8;
    const u64_t m_action          : 8;
    const u64_t ReservedByte3     : 5;
    const u64_t m_testbit1        : 1;
    const u64_t m_testbit2        : 1;
    const u64_t m_cmd_failure     : 1;
    const u64_t m_module_code     : 4;
    const u64_t m_file_code       : 8;
    const u64_t ReservedByte7     : 4;
    const u64_t m_line_no         : 16;
}Status
```

The fact, that no leaks are seen with GCC, but only with Clang makes me think this to be some issue with Clang. (With Clang, I mean it could be **libcxxabi** as well)

I was navigating through the source for clang, & **__cxa_get_globals()** is the function where a **calloc()** call is made. I am not yet sure of the execution flow for clang.

Any idea or any inputs which could confirm this to be a Clang issue & not my code issue?

Here's the clang version I am using. The code is compiled with C++11, additionally with '-stdlib=libc++, '-lc++', '-lc++abi'.

```
[user~]$ clang --version
clang version 7.1.0
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/bin
```

- Update: This exception is raised from the constructor.

---

**Update**
I wrote another dummy code to see the behaviour with Clang, & it seems the issue is actually with the Clang (libc++abi).

Have a look at the below naive code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class Positive {
    int m_number1;
 public:
    Positive() : m_number1(10) {
    }

    Positive(int no) {
        if (no < 0) {
//            throw 100;
              throw std::invalid_argument("Send positive nu");
        } else {
            m_number1 = no;
        }
    }

    ~Positive() {
    }

    void print() {
        std::cout<< "Value of member is: " <<m_number1 <<std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    try {
        Positive p1;
        p1.print();

        Positive p2(100);
        p2.print();

        Positive p3(-10);
        p3.print();

    } catch(...) {
        std::cout << "Some Exception occured" <<std::endl;
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Even on executing the above code, I saw the same result on Valgrind. Here's the output:

```
[user]$ valgrind --leak-check=full --leak-resolution=high --show-leak-kinds=all ./a.out
==119789== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==119789== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==119789== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==119789== Command: ./a.out
==119789==
Value of member is: 10
Value of member is: 100
Some Exception occured
==119789==
==119789== HEAP SUMMARY:
==119789==     in use at exit: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==119789==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 201 bytes allocated
==119789==
==119789== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==119789==    at 0x4C2BFB9: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:762)
==119789==    by 0x40FF830: __cxxabiv1::__calloc_with_fallback(unsigned long, unsigned long) (in /usr/local/lib/libc++abi.so.1.0)
==119789==    by 0x40FE946: __cxa_get_globals (in /usr/local/lib/libc++abi.so.1.0)
==119789==    by 0x4101287: __cxa_throw (in /usr/local/lib/libc++abi.so.1.0)
==119789==    by 0x4014B0: Positive::Positive(int) (in /home/user/test/a.out)
==119789==    by 0x4010F9: main (in /home/user/test/a.out)
==119789==
==119789== LEAK SUMMARY:
==119789==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==119789==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==119789==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==119789==    still reachable: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==119789==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==119789==
==119789== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==119789== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
[user]$
```

Interestingly, it shows 3 allocations made. Which I am assuming to be something related to the 3rd object, but how can I ensure that is cleared (or not allocated itself)?

Probably, the same thing can help me fix my original code.

Comment: Without seeing the code snippet its impossible to tell if the warnings was correct or not. But if you have manual memory allocations that are not in smart pointers (for example) then yes, it is possible for a `throw` to cause a memory leak.

Comment: @CoryKramer added the snippet for the function under test

Comment: what's `Status`?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, Status is a structure

Comment: `s_last_error`  is a global variable judging by `__cxa_get_globals` call?  It's likely it was allocating memory ahead of time  and string is still allocated after `throw `. does diagnostic change if you use  `s_last_error += AdditionalMsg;` It's kind of false positive then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also found this problem. It actually occurs if your code throws anything at least once, so the simplest reproduction scenario is just running this code:

```
int
main()
{
    try {
        throw 42;
    } catch (int) {}
}
```

However, if you throw several times there is still just one 16-bytes "leaked" block (which is not really leaked, since it is still reachable from some global variable). Digging into libc++abi library [sources](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/d480f968ad8b56d3ee4a6b6df5532d485b0ad01e/libcxxabi/src/cxa_exception_storage.cpp#L75) shows that such blocks are actually allocated once per thread to hold some exception processing context, and each one is freed when a thread is destroyed since it uses TLS and have proper destructor registered. So after all, it looks totally safe and is not an issue.